# Passing the user object and a filtered object list into a custom SearchView subclass

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-haystack

So I have a template that is set to the generic haystack url:

> ```
> url(r'^$', search_view_factory(
>     view_class=SearchView,
>     template='base.html',
>     searchqueryset=sqs,
>     form_class=ModelSearchForm
> ), name='haystack_search'),
> ```

in which I need to drop something like `tasks.filter(completed=False).order_by('priority', 'dueDate')`.
Now in the template I can get to the tasks, by `user.get_profile.task_set.all`, but I cannot execute the filtering and the ordering.
That would be easy to solve via a views entry, but since the haystack doesn't point to a view, how can I pass the filtered and ordered list into the template?
I need to mention that the filtered & ordered list has nothing to do with the search functionality of haystack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `SearchView`, create a subclass and define the method `extra_context`:

```
class MySearchView(SearchView):

    def extra_context(self):
        return { 'ordered_tasks': ... }
```

This method must return a dictionary with additional context variables.

Lastly, pass this new view class to `view_class` in the call to `search_view_factory`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. There is another problem, though. I can get the ordered list, but I need to request the `user` object, something like `request.user` in an ordinary view - to be able to get the logged in user's tasks.

Comment: You can add the request context processor to have access to `request` in your templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request - You can then use `request.user` in your templates.

Comment: Well, this works just fine, but I need to do some logic in the template: `{% if task.member = user.get_profile %}`. And since I think I will  need to write all my views using this technique (in order to enable haystack searching in all of them), isn't there a way of requesting the user inside my custom `EntitySeachView(SearchView)`?

Comment: Actually I managed to do that, inside `def extra_context(self)` by `self.request.user`, but I still can't access the `task_set`. For now I'll use what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Simeon's answer, and some other stackoverflow question that made me aware of the possibility of using `self.request.user` inside of a `def extra_context(self):` method of a `CustomSearchView(SearchView)` class, I was able to solve my problem, like so. 
         Inside `views.py`:

```
from haystack.views import SearchView
class MySearchView(SearchView):    

    def extra_context(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            member = self.request.user.get_profile()
        else:
            # just fooling the haystack config, since this view is set to localhost
            return { 'x' : 0 }  # which would be equivalent to a direct_to_template view


        # getting member tasks
        tasks = list()
        for elem in member.task_set.all().filter(completed=False).order_by('priority', 'dueDate')[:5]:
            tasks.append(elem)

        return { 'tasks': tasks }
```

And in the tamplate:

```
<a href="tasks/" style="color: #ffffff">Tasks</a>
    <ul id="tasksPane">
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <li><a href="/tasks/{{ task.id }}" id="tasksP" {% if task.priority == 'c' %} style="color: #99ff44" {% endif %}
                                                            {% if task.priority == 'b' %} style="color: #024dac" {% endif %}
                                                            {% if task.priority == 'a' %} style="color: #aa0022" {% endif %}
                ><input type="checkbox" name="task" value="completed">{{ task.task }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

This way, *I do not need to do any major logic in the template*, which is what I needed, and I gather that django would disapprove such an approach, since it wouldn't allow the `filter` and `order_by` methods in the template.
And of course, in my `urls.py`:

```
# haystack
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView, search_view_factory
sqs = SearchQuerySet()
from member.views import MySearchView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', search_view_factory(
        view_class=MySearchView,
        template='base.html',
        searchqueryset=sqs,
        form_class=ModelSearchForm
    ), name='haystack_search'),
)
```